# Queries in the Proof of Implicit Function Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have been reading Analysis on Manifolds by Munkres but I am stuck on tiny details in the proof of Implicit Function Theorem provided by the author.

> **Implicit Function Theorem** - Let $A$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^{k + n}$ and $f: A \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be of class $C^r$. $f( \bf{x}, \bf{y})$ denotes value of $f$ for ${\bf{x}} \in \mathbb{R}^k$ and
> ${\bf{y}} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Given $ ({\bf a, b}) \in A $ such that
> $f({\bf a, b}) = {\bf 0}$ and
> \begin{equation} 
> \det \frac{\partial f}{\partial {\bf y}}({\bf a, b}) \ne 0 
> \end{equation}
> Then there is a neighborhood $B$ of $\bf a$ in $\mathbb{R}^k$ and a
> unique continuous function $g : B \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $g({\bf a}) = \bf b$ and   \begin{equation} f({\bf x}, g({\bf x})) = \bf 0
> \end{equation}
> for all ${\bf x} \in B$. Function $g$ belongs to class
> $C^r$ as well.

**Proof**

1. We construct a function $F : A \to \mathbb{R}^{k + n}$ such that $F({\bf x, y}) = ({\bf x}, f({\bf x, y}))$. Then $F$ maps open set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{k + n} \to \mathbb{R}^{k +n}$. Now
   \begin{equation}
   DF = \quad\begin{bmatrix} I_k & 0 \\ \partial f / \partial {\bf x} & \partial f / \partial {\bf y} \end{bmatrix}
   \end{equation}
   It is obvious $\det DF \ne 0$ since $\det {\partial f}/{\partial {\bf y}}|_{\bf a, b} \ne 0$. Thus we can apply inverse function theorem to $F$. Therefore, there exists and open set $U \times V$ of $\mathbb{R}^{k + n}$ where $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^k$ and $V$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that inverse function $G$ such that

- $F$ maps $U \times V \to W$ in $1-1$ fashion containing $({\bf a},{\bf 0})$
- $G: W \to U \times V$ is of class $C^r$.

2. Since $G = F^{-1}$,
   \begin{align}
   F({\bf x}, {\bf y}) = ({\bf x}, f({\bf x}, {\bf y}))\\
   \implies ({\bf x}, {\bf y}) = G({\bf x}, f({\bf x}, {\bf y}))
   \end{align}
3. $\color{red} {\textrm{Then we can write } G({\bf x}, {\bf z}) = ({\bf x}, h({\bf x}, {\bf z}))}$ for ${\bf x} \in \mathbb{R}^k$ and ${\bf z} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. $h$ is a function of class $C^r$ mapping $W$ in to $\mathbb{R}^n$.
4. Let $B$ be a $\color{red}{\textrm{connected }}$ neighborhood of ${\bf a}$ in $\mathbb{R}^k$ such that $B \times 0$ is contained in $W$. If ${\bf x} \in B$, then $({\bf x}, {\bf 0}) \in W$. Therefore,
   \begin{align}
   &G({\bf x}, {\bf 0}) = ({\bf x}, h({\bf x}, {\bf 0}))\\
   \implies & ({\bf x}, {\bf 0}) = F({\bf x}, h({\bf x}, {\bf 0})) = ({\bf x}, f({\bf x}, h({\bf x}, {\bf 0})))\\
   \implies & {\bf 0} = f({\bf x}, h({\bf x}, {\bf 0}))
   \end{align}
5. We set $g({\bf x}) = h({\bf x}, {\bf 0})$ for ${\bf x} \in B$.

Here are the two main queries I have ;

1. **How do we know that there exists a function $h$ such that $y$ can be written as a function of ${\bf x}$ and ${\bf z} = f({\bf x}, {\bf y})$?** In a way, this seems circular. We wrote ${\bf y}$ as a function of other variables while trying to prove the implicit function theorem.
2. **What is so special about the connected neighborhood?**

Comment: Well, as to 1, we can always write a function $G$ in this way, if it is determined by $x,z$. The fact that $h(x,z)=y$ is from the inverse function theorem, since $G=F^{-1}$ on the mentioned set.

Comment: @NL1992 Can you please explain that in a bit more detail?

Comment: From the inverse function theorem, there exists $G$ which is the inverse of $F$ on an open neighborhood of $(a,b)$ and we can write $G(x,z)=(x,h(x,z))=F^{-1}(x,z)$ and $F^{-1}(x,z)=(x,y_z)$ where $y_z$ is the one giving $f(x,y_z)=z$.